# MarkLogic 8 - request not getting timed out - keeps retrying after logging XDMP-XDQPNOSESSION

Tags: logging, marklogic, marklogic-8, appserver

We are using `MarkLogic-8` with a setup of three nodes (two `Forests` on each). We have an `HTTP App-Server` with `request timeout` and `session timeout` set to 30 mins.
An incoming request through this `App-Server` has been running for over 8 hours before it was cancelled manually. Upon looking up the logs we found that this request was retried for 44 times with `XDMP-XDQPNOSESSION` entries.

> 2020-08-04 17:36:13.879 Debug: Retrying xdmp:eval 7547772792649456554 Update 41 because **XDMP-XDQPNOSESSION: No XDQP session**, client=xx.xxx.x.xxx, request=probeByHash, session=14574561708811728252, target=16982022523143157068

Now the question is - why this `request` keeps getting retried instead of getting `timed out` (in 30 mins)?
We had other requests running in parallel with this one, all (except this) completed successfully without any such error/scenario.

Comment: If you have a 30 minute timeout, then that request should not have been running for 8 hours. Are there any other indications of issues/trouble (XDQP Restarts, host restart, error, lots of deadlocks, etc)? Can you post the code from the eval? What version of MarkLogic 8 (which is EOL) are you running? Is upgrading to 9 or 10 an option? There may be bug fixes and other enhancements to avoid "stuck" transactions.

Comment: Thanks for replying. There are no XDQP restart, host restart messages, a few deadlocks but those involve different docs from the ones the concerned request is working upon. Can't share the code but can give you some insights - code fetches huge numbers of docs from database (~93k) applies XSLT on each doc; creates zip of these XSLT transformed docs and saves in database (xdmp:invoke-function is used while fetching the docs in query mode to avoid locks on documents). We are using MarkLogic version - 8.0-7.

Comment: It's strange that it retried over 40 times and ran so long. Maybe somehow escaping limits and checks that would have killed it. I recall some bug fixes in 8 to kill such runaway threads that get "stuck". You might consider opening a Support case, but MarkLogic 8 is EOL so they will likely tell you to upgrade. Even a newer version of 8 might be helpful, if you aren't ready to move to 9 or 10 yet.